# sort 2 properties alpabetically if more than one occurrence of first js

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks like this

```
var arr =  [
      {
        firstName: 'Maria',
        lastName: 'S.',
        country: 'Peru',
        continent: 'Americas',
        age: 30,
        language: 'C'
      }, {
        firstName: 'Agustin',
        lastName: 'V.',
        country: 'Uruguay',
        continent: 'Americas',
        age: 19,
        language: 'JavaScript'
      }, {
        firstName: 'Precious',
        lastName: 'G.',
        country: 'South Africa',
        continent: 'Africa',
        age: 22,
        language: 'JavaScript'
      }, {
        firstName: 'Nikau',
        lastName: 'R.',
        country: 'New Zealand',
        continent: 'Oceania',
        age: 39,
        language: 'Ruby'
      }
]
```

I am arranging the array sorted alphabetically by the programming language. However, in some cases there are some developers that code in the same language, which I then want to sort alphabetically by the first name:

I have written the following function which I thought should work.

First I am sorting the languages alphabetically, and then in the second sorting function if the languages are the same they should be sorted alphabetically by first name. I think the error is most likely with what I am returning if the `a.language != b.language` but I am not sure.

Please see the code below. Can anyone spot where my misunderstanding is?

```
function sortByLanguage(list) {

    return list.sort((a, b) => {
      if(a.language < b.language) return -1;
      if(a.language > b.language) return 1;
      return 0;
    }).sort((a, b) => {

        if(a.language === b.language) {
          if(a.firstName < b.firstName) return -1;
          if(a.firstName > b.firstName) return 1;
           return 0;
        }
        return 0;


    });
}
```

Comment: If you chain sorts, you don’t guarantee that the first sorting condition still holds.

Comment: @Xufox, ah ok. is this why it wasn't working?

Answer (score 3):

You try to sort the array first by language and then sort again with the first name. That does not work, because the second sorting does not respect the first sorting.

You could use a chained approach by using the default operator ([logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())), that means if the first part does not resolve to a truthy value, then the second part is evaluated.

```
return a.language.localeCompare(b.language) || a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//     sort first by language and if equal
//     it returns zero, then the other part
//     is evaluated
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                             sort by firstName
```

```js
var array = [{ firstName: 'Maria', lastName: 'S.', country: 'Peru', continent: 'Americas', age: 30, language: 'C' }, { firstName: 'Agustin', lastName: 'V.', country: 'Uruguay', continent: 'Americas', age: 19, language: 'JavaScript' }, { firstName: 'Precious', lastName: 'G.', country: 'South Africa', continent: 'Africa', age: 22, language: 'JavaScript' }, { firstName: 'Nikau', lastName: 'R.', country: 'New Zealand', continent: 'Oceania', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' }]

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.language.localeCompare(b.language) || a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: great answer. However, I tried to not chain both `sort` and it still didn't work. Does that make sense, even though I separated them? First sorted them by language. and then another unchained sort method sorting them by `first name` if the languages are the same?

Comment: @RaulRodriguez, you need only one call of sort. (or i don't get what you want ...?)

Comment: no, what you provided works perfectly. but i am just wondering why when i did two separate sorts it didn't work.

Comment: you have not a stable sorting with only one item to sort.